# Using Docker version of Lightning Network daemon to gain understanding

Tags: bitcoind, lightning-network

In trying to understand the Lightning Network further. To do so, I was looking at the link below (it shows how it is being used with Docker):
https://hub.docker.com/r/cdecker/lightning-ci/

Based on the information in the link, I had questions.

- **STEP 1**: # Returns an address  cli/lightning-cli newaddr
  **^^^^ Ques**: Is this a new address created on LIGHTNING NETWORK? Is it on the BITCOIN NETWORK? Is it in "No-Mans-Land/Purgatory"? Where
  is the Private-Key? Can many addresses be created?
- **STEP** 2: # Returns a transaction id  bitcoin-cli -testnet sendtoaddress  
  **^^^^ Ques**: So, if you forget / lose this address (after sending money to it), you are out-of-luck? Also, "bitcoin-cli" commands are
  executed under the "btcd" BITCOIN dameon?
- **STEP 3**: # Retrieves the raw transaction  bitcoin-cli -testnet getrawtransaction
- **STEP 4**: # Notifies `lightningd` that there are now funds available: cli/lightning-cli addfunds 
  **^^^^ Ques**: It is at this point the funds are *actually* added to the LIGHTNING NETWORK. I take it that the funds are associated with
  the  created in STEP 1 above?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you are following is using the `bitcoind` wallet, so the address generated in Step1 will be derived from your `bitcoind` master private key.

Checking the current [c-lightning documentation](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning), this seems outdated, step 3 and 4 are no longer needed.

- Q1: this returns an address from the `bitcoind` wallet
- Q2: you send a bitcoin transaction from any wallet you like, here the local `bitcoind` (Bitcoin Core) node is used.
- Q4: here, you notify `lightningd` to use the funds when opening channels. But no channel is opened and thus no funds are committed to the Lightning Network yet. (as mentioned, seems obsolete now with current release)